# get top element for dictionary python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to get most common words in a dictionary I created.
I read about it an i saw that the answer is using sorted function and [:n] in order to ask for number of elements.

my problem is that my dictionary is a bit different to what I saw - it's like that:

```
[{"count":27,"stem":"obama","term":"obama"},{"count":20,"stem":"boehner","term":"boehner"},{"count":4,"stem":"tax","term":"tax"},
{"count":3,"stem":"daley","term":"daley"},{"count":3,"stem":"couldn","term":"couldn"},{"count":2,"stem":"trillion","term":"trillion"}]
```

so in this example obama is mention 27 time boehner 20 and tax 2 - so lets say I want to get top 5 most common words, how do I do that?

Comment: You don't have a dictionary, you have a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [39]: L = [{"count":27,"stem":"obama","term":"obama"},{"count":20,"stem":"boehner","term":"boehner"},{"count":4,"stem":"tax","term":"tax"},
{"count":3,"stem":"daley","term":"daley"},{"count":3,"stem":"couldn","term":"couldn"},{"count":2,"stem":"trillion","term":"trillion"}]

In [40]: counts = collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable([d['term']]*d['count'] for d in L))

In [41]: counts.most_common(5)
Out[41]: [('obama', 27), ('boehner', 20), ('tax', 4), ('daley', 3), ('couldn', 3)]
```

Don't forget to `import itertools, collections`

Comment: I get this error

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @user3488862: then, your question doesn't show the actual data you're working with, because my answer is straight from the python REPL